# Css3 keyframe cycle slider?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

What's up folks .. i've been training myself on this marvelous world of Css3 keyframes.
I've seen a couple of approaches about sliders made with 100% css, but i'm looking for something different.
What I'm trying to do is a slider that moves all its pictures at the same time (they all are visible to the user),while they are moving, by the time the first picture is going out of visibility e.g (left side),it should be coming from the right, and the same with the other pictures.. and that till earth stops :D.
It's understandable what I'm trying to do ? But i can't figure out how to do it.
Give a hand please! 
Thanks for your help.
 Here is some code :

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <div id="slideshow">

                <figure class="teste">
                    <img src="images/daya1.jpg" alt="">
                </figure>
                 <figure class="teste">
                    <img src="images/daya2.jpg" alt="Profile of a Red kite">
                </figure>
                 <figure class="teste3">
                    <img src="images/daya3.jpg" alt="Profile of a Red kite">
                </figure>
                 <figure class="test4">
                    <img src="images/daya4.jpg" alt="Profile of a Red kite">
                </figure>

            </div>
```

And here is some other code

```
#wrapper{

margin: auto;

background-color: black;
width: 1100px;
}

#slideshow {
    margin-left: 20px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow figure{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow figure.teste{
    -webkit-animation-name:sliderleft,slidertop,sliderright,sliderbottom;
    -webkit-animation-duration:5s, 5s,5s,5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0s,4s,9s,17s;
    /*-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;*/
}
@-webkit-keyframes sliderleft{
from {left: 0px;}
to {left: -300px;}
}


  @-webkit-keyframes slidertop{
    0% {top: 0px;}
    100% {top: 200px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sliderright{
    from { left: 0px;}
    to {left: 750px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes sliderbottom{
    from { bottom: 0px;}
    to {bottom: 750px;}
}
```

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 2):

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PWsSb/1/)

Since you want the elements to repeat on the right side as they slide out from the left, you'll have to use a separate (but similar) animation for each picture. For me that was

```
@-webkit-keyframes sliderfirst {
    0%   { left:    0px; }
    12%  { left: -300px; }
    13%  { left: 1200px; opacity:0; }
    14%  {   opacity: 1; }
    25%  { left:  900px; }
    50%  { left:  600px; }
    75%  { left:  300px; }
    100% { left:    0px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidersecond {
    0%   { left:  300px; }
    25%  { left:    0px; }
    37%  { left: -300px; }
    38%  { left: 1200px; opacity:0; }
    39%  {   opacity: 1; }
    50%  { left:  900px; }
    75%  { left:  600px; }
    100% { left:  300px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes sliderthird {
    0%   { left:  600px; }
    25%  { left:  300px; }    
    50%  { left:    0px; }
    62%  { left: -300px; }
    63%  { left: 1200px; opacity:0; }
    64%  {   opacity: 1; }
    75%  { left:  900px; }
    100% { left:  600px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes sliderfourth {
    0%   { left:  900px; }
    25%  { left:  600px; }    
    50%  { left:  300px; }    
    75%  { left:    0px; }
    87%  { left: -300px; }
    88%  { left: 1200px; opacity:0; }
    89%  {   opacity: 1; }
    100% { left:  900px; }
}
```

and applying it by using `nth-child` and shorthand to save space

```
#slideshow figure.teste {
    position:absolute;
}
#slideshow figure.teste:nth-child(4n-3) {
    left:0px;
    -webkit-animation:sliderfirst 15s linear infinite;
}
#slideshow figure.teste:nth-child(4n-2) {
    left:300px;
    -webkit-animation:slidersecond 15s linear infinite;
}
#slideshow figure.teste:nth-child(4n-1) {
    left:600px;
    -webkit-animation:sliderthird 15s linear infinite;
}
#slideshow figure.teste:nth-child(4n) {
    left:900px;
    -webkit-animation:sliderfourth 15s linear infinite;
}
```

I hope it suits your needs. Let me know if you have any questions!