# How to creating multiple image sliders/gallery with range sliders

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am learning CSS and PHP and JavaScript. I want to create an image/gallery slider using HTML range slider. I have created the design so far. I just want an image and range slider to work. I am supposed to use JavaScript to make the range sliders work but it is not working. I've searched through hours of youtube videos but I am unsuccessful. Please I need some help as I am still learning. Below are my HTML and JavaScript code.

```
        <div class="container">/*my container*/
                 <div class="slides">/*division class for picture slides*/
                    <img src="img1.png"> /*pictures*/
                    <img src="img2.png">
                    <img src="img3.png">
                    <img src="img4.png">
                    <img src="img5.png">
                    <img src="img6.png">
                    <img src="img7.png">
                    <img src="img8.png">
                    <img src="img9.png">
                    <img src="img10.png">
                    <img src="img11.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
   
        
        <div class ="slide-container"> /*range slider container*/
             <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange"/>
        </div>
  
/*Java Script Code*/
<script>
   var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
   var output = document.getElementById("slider");
   var slideIndex = 1;
   showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        } 
        function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        }
 </script>
```

[image: The image below is what I want to accomplish]

Comment: What doesn't work? What does `animate.js` do?

Comment: Animate.js is used for animation in JavaScript. Don't worry about it. My JavaScript code is not working. I have already edited my question

Comment: Hi Respawn! To increase the chance of getting an answer, edit the question to include a SNIPPET using the "<>" tool. That makes it easier for people to replicate the problem. At the moment you have some curious things, like comment text with "//" before it, in HTML (where that is not the comment symbol) and more serious problems references to the non-existent functions "showSlides" and the nonexistent variable "slider"

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Javascript:

```
function slider(val){
    var doc = document.getElementById(val);
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    if(doc != undefined){
      for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++){
        img[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      doc.style.display = "block";
    }
 }
```

CSS:

```
img{display: none;}
img:first-of-type{display: block;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="img1.png" id="1">
      <img src="img2.png" id="2">
      <img src="img3.png" id="3">
      <img src="img4.png" id="4">
      <img src="img5.png" id="5">
      <img src="img6.png" id="6">
      <img src="img7.png" id="7">
      <img src="img8.png" id="8">
      <img src="img9.png" id="9">
      <img src="img10.png" id="10">
      <img src="img11.png" id="11">
    </div>
</div>
<div class ="slide-container">
  <input oninput="slider(this.value)" onchange="slider(this.value)" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution did not work. It just made my slides to disappear as soon as I clicked on the range slider. It did not slide through the pictures like what typical image sliders do

Comment: When you want a 'real' slider you need to check out "@Keyframes". My solution focused on changing the picture according to the slider's value. For the Keyframes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129473/css3-keyframe-cycle-slider & https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp
What is your actual problem with the slider in general? What do you want to achieve with the slider and what exactly does not work?

Comment: I want to create a responsive slideshow gallery that moves to the next picture once you drag the range slider. I want it to work like a regular slideshow gallery but the difference is that instead of buttons or arrows, the range slider will be used to move to the next image when users want to view other pictures in the gallery. The use of any keyframe is not necessary for this project. Neither do I want the pictures to change according to the slider's value. I Just want to slider to display the next picture or previous picture when a user drags it back and forth like a slideshow gallery

Comment: Then I would recommand using my solution and adapting the min and max value of the slider to the image value. With the slider solution the first image sould be at the beginning and the last image on the last value. When you have buttons or arrows there is no defined begging or end - or is that what you try to code with the slider?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to code with the slider, not buttons and arrows. I have used your solution but it is making the image disappear as soon as I click on the slider.  It is not moving to the next or previous picture like a normal gallery slider supposed to do.

Comment: I tried it and for me it worked totally fine and changed the img according to the slider value. Have you adjusted the value of the range slider to the number of images you used?